# How to modify share sheet and add custom button in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, share

I need to modify the share sheet functionality in my SwiftUI app. I am looking to add a custom button to the share sheet interface. However, I'm facing some challenges in implementing this feature.

Could someone kindly provide guidance or share insights on how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
```

**Create a Share Button:**
Add a share button to your SwiftUI view. This button will trigger the share sheet when tapped.

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Button(action: {
                // Code to share content
                shareContent()
            }) {
                Text("Share")
            }
        }
       
    func shareContent() {
        let textToShare = "Check out this awesome content!"
        let itemsToShare = [textToShare] // Add more items if needed (e.g., URLs, images)
        
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: itemsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

You can customize the sharing options by adding more items to itemsToShare. For example, if you want to share an image, you can include the image data in itemsToShare.

```
let imageToShare = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
let itemsToShare: [Any] = [textToShare, imageToShare]
```

Run your app and tap the "Share" button to see the share sheet with the content you specified.

Comment: thank you for your response , but i need to add action button to share sheet when user share from any place in app not from my app only like Pinterest app

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShareSheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isShareSheetPresented.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Share")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShareSheetPresented, content: {
            // Custom Share Sheet
            ShareSheet(activityItems: ["Hello, world!"])
        })
    }
}

struct ShareSheet: View {
    var activityItems: [Any]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Share")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()

            Button(action: {
                // Handle your custom action
                print("Custom action tapped")
            }) {
                Text("Custom Action")
            }
            .padding()

            Divider()

            Button(action: {
                // Share functionality
                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
                UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }) {
                Text("Share")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```